# Python :: Storing in a JSON format after finding specific string from a text file

Tags: python, json

This is my code, i which i am able to fetch the Table_name, Schema_name and Column_names from a text file (which consists DDLs). I want to store only those records in JSON file. I am able to create the JSON file but the required data is not stored. Please help me out here.

```
#----------Schema Name should be present
#---------Not working with DDL's having compress in columns
import re #importing regular expression module
import json #importing JSON library
import sys
#Function to extract tablename
def table_name(ddl):
    table = re.search(r'(.*) table (.*) .*', ddl, re.M|re.I)
    if table:
        tb = table.group(2)
        tbl1 = tb.split(".")
        tbl2 = tbl1[1].split(",")
        print("Table: " + tbl2[0])
    else:
        a = 1
#Function to extract Schemaname
def Schema_name(ddl):
    Schema = re.search(r'(.*) table (.*) .*', ddl, re.M|re.I)
    
    if Schema:
        sch = Schema.group(2)
        schm = sch.split(".")
        print("Schema: " + schm[0])
    else:
        a = 1
#Function to extract Columns and datatypes
def Columns(ddl):
    rm_FK = re.sub('.*FOREIGN.*\n?','',ddl, flags = re.I)
    rm_Par = re.sub('.*PARTITION.*\n?','',rm_FK, flags = re.I)
    
    #print(rm_Par)
    ddl1 = rm_Par.replace("\n", " ")
    ddl2 = re.sub(r' +', ' ', ddl1)
    rm_PK = re.search('(.*) PRIMARY.*',ddl2, re.M|re.I)
    if rm_PK:
        txt = rm_PK.group(1)
        #print(txt)
        Col = re.search('(.*) \( (.*)\)', txt, re.M|re.I)
        if Col:
            str = Col.group(2)
            #print(Col.group(2))
            str1 = re.sub(r' +', ' ', str)
            result = re.split(', ', str1.strip())
            print(result)
        else:
            a=1     
    else:
        a = 1
        
f = open("DDL_Teradata.txt", "r") 
list1 = []
FD = f.read()
lines = FD.split(";")
for i in lines: 
    temp_list = { table_name(i),
    Schema_name(i),
    Columns(i)}
list1.append(temp_list)
print(temp_list)
print(list1)
f.close()

with open('ddl.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(list1, fp, indent = 4)
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also include the output of your program and the contents of the file that is created. You mention that you are able to create the file, but that it does not contain what you expect. So please show us what it contains instead.

Comment: I attempted your last 3 lines above with `ls = [1, 2, 3, "asda", "weqweq", "asdas"]` and it works perfect. Do you get any errors, can you include some sample from your list?

Comment: Table: sales
Schema: sample_db
['store_id INTEGER NOT NULL', 'product_id INTEGER NOT NULL', "sales_date DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd' NOT NULL", 'total_revenue DECIMAL(13,2)', 'total_sold INTEGER', 'note VARCHAR(256)'] --this is the o/p i am getting.. Need to store this in JSON file.

Comment: DDL present in Source file ::
CREATE TABLE sample_db.sales (
      store_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
      product_id    INTEGER NOT NULL,
      sales_date    DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd' NOT NULL,
      total_revenue DECIMAL(13,2),
      total_sold    INTEGER,
      note          VARCHAR(256)
      FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES WITH CHECK OPTION parent_table(product_id) 
    primary INDEX (store_id, product_id, sales_date)
    PARTITION BY RANGE_N(sales_date BETWEEN DATE '2001-01-01' AND DATE '2001-05-31' );

File contains more than one DDL